# Mathematica can solve the eigenvalues of a large sparse non-Hermitian (non-symmetrical) matrix?

Tags: eigenvalues

The Arnoldi algorithms of function "Eigensystems" in Mathematica can be used to solve the eigenvalues of a Large Sparse non-Hermitian (non-symmetrical) Complex matrix?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is. Are you asking if Arnoldi algorithms can be used to solve sparse matrix problems in Mathematica? If so, yes. See the `Method` section under the `Options` section on the documentation page for `Eigensystem`.

Comment: Then the Arnoldi algorithms can be used for complex non-symmetrical matrix ?

Comment: Yes, it can be used to compute _few_ eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to find few generalized eigenvalues of a large non-hermitian complex sparse matrix using the Arnoldi method and i get the error that "The matrix ... is not Hermitian or real and symmetric". The matrix refered in the error message is the "generalized" one, the one in the right-hand side of the generalized eigenvalue equation.
No error appear for a regular eigenvalue problem (not generalized).
Is it a limitation of the Arnoldi method ?